# Security Error when loading local files in own protocol handler

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, local-files, protocol-handler

I'm creating Firefox addon that registers new protocol which should provide HTML to Firefox from file stored on disk (generated by binary exe).

I have problem with images in  tags and (probably) css styles that refer to local file. They aren't load properly and I'm getting a message in the errorconsole like this :

> Security Error: Content at moz-nullprincipal:{afde522e-6b29-4359-9959-c46c749687f6} may not load or link to file:///E:/xowa_app/user/anonymous/app/img/file/magnify-clip.png.

My protocol flags : nsIProtocolHandler.URI_IS_LOCAL_FILE | nsIProtocolHandler.URI_IS_LOCAL_RESOURCE | nsIProtocolHandler.URI_STD | nsIProtocolHandler.URI_INHERITS_SECURITY_CONTEXT. (I don't know whether I understand properly [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProtocolHandler#Constants))

nsIProtocolHandler interface specs need to me that I implement function to creating new channel ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannel)) when it is opening URI by the protocol. I create a channel from URI located on disk (html generated by program). The channel has owner property that "grant or deny privileges" and I setted even the owner to system principal who "passes all security checks" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security_check_basics#Principals)) but the errors are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to that just removing URI_INHERITS_SECURITY_CONTEXT flag (and leaving change owner to system principal) resolves my problem although I don't know when there is need to use this flag.